# How to check if windows service can be started?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I created a program to check if any service was stopped.

But if I disable the service and I try to start the serivce, an exception happens.

How to check if service can be started or the status is disabled?

I'm using ServiceController class.

The code:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("serviceName");

if (!service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running))
    service.Start();
```

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud What does netstat have to do with starting or stopping services?

Comment: Some code? Detail of the exception? Or do you think SO is a home for clairvoyant software engineers?

Comment: You wouldn't want to disable the service, once its disabled it cannot be started.  You would need to make sure the service is set to autostart or delayed start or Manual to be able to start it. Open up services and find a service that is disabled and you will see the start button is grayed out.

Comment: See this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939611/get-the-disabled-status-of-a-windows-service

Comment: Hi, happens the following exception: "Unable to start a service on computer '.'"

Comment: I changed my first post adding the code.

Comment: Is it necessary to know in advance? Does catching the specific exception not provide the information you're looking for?

Comment: I knew you'd say that, @daveL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if the service can be started, you use the following

```
ServiceController svc = new ServiceController("serviceName");

if  ((svc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||
     (svc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
{
    try
    {
       svc.Start();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       //log, abort, drink beer, etc
    }
}
```

Checking against anything but `running` is problematic b/c there are other states to consider.

Checking if a service is disabled is a bit more involved.  Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399332/2779990).

Comment: I thought exists a best form of do this. But I'll do it that way even. Thanks a lot.